# C++ read from file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, file-handling

when I try to debug this code to read from a file and display it, the console screen comes and goes quickly and I don't understand why it's doing this. Can anyone help me please?

```
#include "Questions.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MAXITEMS = 10;

struct quiz
{
    string question;
    string anser;
};


int main ()
{
  string str;
  ifstream ifs("Questions2.txt.txt");
  getline (ifs,str);
  cout << "first line of the file is " << str << ".\n";
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint on the last line of main?

Comment: Because computers are fast and if you don't ask them to stop, they won't!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with ifs.open, and then assure yourself by using `ifs.is_open ()` function with an if and an error code, I always use it and it worth

and of course, use a breakpoint before the return (clicking it or using `system ("pause")`

Answer (score 2):

You should click some breakpoints in VS window.Then when you press <kbd>F5</kbd>,it will pause at breakpoint, then it will run continue until you press <kbd>F5</kbd> again.
Or,if you make sure your code is correct.You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.This means "Run Without Debug".
This situation,your program will run to end and suggest you "Press any key to continue".
Sorry for my bad english. Hope you can understand.

Comment: +1 for Ctrl+F5. That will solve the disappearing command line window, if he doesn't want to debug.

Answer (score 1):

You can try including a pause function. This way it will display your data and then wait for a response. I've included the function I typically use.

```
void myPause()
{
      cout << "    Press enter to continue... ";
      char blank[8];
      cin.getline(blank,8);
      cin.sync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you run with some breakpoints, Visual Studio will close the window after the program terminates.

If you want the window to stay on the screen, use Debug->Start without debugging

Or, add a breakpoint at return 1;

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>F10</kbd> instead of <kbd>F5</kbd>. By pressing <kbd>F10</kbd>, you can go line by line